# Safari WebDriver throws exception when trying to create on a Mac

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am trying to create a Safari WebDriver on Mac OSX 10.9.5 with latest Selenium:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true); //if you wish safari to forget session everytime
return (driver = new SafariDriver(options));
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory

Answer (score 0):

The Safari driver [has a dependency upon Netty](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?l=java&q=netty%20safari&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), as can be seen from [the Maven POM](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.53.0/maven/safari-driver/pom.xml#L21).

So wherever you use `selenium-safari-driver-XXX.jar` you also need a Netty JAR, e.g. my project has a `netty-3.9.0-Final.jar`.

You haven't told us anything about how you build or deploy your application, but if you don't have a Netty JAR to hand, you can download the latest 3.x install [from here](http://netty.io/downloads.html).